# How to change part of an MQTT topic within an ActiveMQ Artemis broker

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

We require all topics to start with a cloud namespace GUID like this:
**490ec63b-8597-3698-bd62-9f19973c1a9b**/manage/cert/roll/temp1

We want to allow devices to publish and subscribe with a namespace token like this:
**{ns}**/manage/cert/roll/cid/temp1

We would have the server replace {ns} with the namespace GUID that the device's x509 cert is registered within in our cloud app.

Thought an MQTT Interceptor was the answer. It gives access to the certs via RemotingConnection and the MqttMessage, but it looks like there is no way to change the topicName in the variableHeader.

Created a broker-plugin, but can't find the override that would accomplish what we need.

Any ideas?